# What is the index name of the PrimaryKey in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a quick question. In my code I am using the `IndexName` parameter to query my respective indexes. This lets my code look like the following: 
`IndexName: config.myIndexName` which is a style I really like. However when using the Primary Key, it looks like you need to leave off the IndexName entirely. I don't like this as I feel it makes my query style less consistent and harder to read.

Does anyone know the "name" of the primary <strike>key</strike> index, so that I can specify the primary <strike>key</strike> index using IndexName?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

The `indexName` parameter must be left blank when referring to the Primary Key in the Query API.

The Primary Key is not considered an Index. You can verify this by clicking over to the Indexes tab of your table and seeing that there are no indexes listed.